# How to get json string from json object in jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I know `jQuery.parseJSON` will convert my json string to json object. Which does the vise versa in jquery (ie) json object to json string... Any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this site:  http://www.json.org/js.html

Include their script and they have a Stringify method which does what you're looking for.

Comment: any useful function in jquery?

Comment: You would need to use a plugin to get it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a jQuery solution, get this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/